# 68k: Adding 0x100 to 9-bit register and doing BEQ.s - how does it make sense?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, motorola

During my current project I found such code:

```
move.w  (0xFFFC0C).l, d0 | read SCSR
andi.w  #0x100, d0       | add 256 to d0
beq.s   location         | branch if LSB = 0x00
```

I cannot get the idea of this fragment. I guess author tried to check the status of the UART, but how does `andi.w` and `beq.s` serves the purpose, when SCSR may contain maximum of 9 bits?

[image]

Comment: It's not adding. It is binary AND operation, exactly as single & in C language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not adding. It is [binary and operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), and in translation to C the code looks as follows:

```
d0 = readSCSR(); // move.w  (0xFFFC0C).l, d0 | read SCSR
if (d0 & 0x100) 
//andi.w  #0x100, d0       | not add, but AND 256 to d0
//beq.s   location         | branch if LSB = 0x00
{
    // do whatever needed
}
location: // else branch to location
```